# Apply parent css rule to children

Tags: html, css, sass

Using SCSS, I want to apply `disabled` styles in `.parent` to its children.

My current SCSS structure is as such:

```
.parent {
   .disabled {
     background: grey;
   }
   > .group {
      ...
      > .input {
          background: white;
        }
      > .icon {
          background: blue;
        }
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent" ng-class="{disabled: el.isDisabled}">
   <div class="group">
      ...
      <textarea class="form-control input">
         ...
      </textarea>
      <div class="icon">
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I apply these styles to `input` and `icon`?

---

For context, what I currently have is quite redundant:

```
.parent {
   > .group {
      ...
      > .input {
           background: white;
           &.disabled {
              background: grey;
           }
        }
      > .icon {
           background: blue;
           &.disabled {
              background: grey;
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `inherit` what you're looking for?

Comment: @SankarshMakam well, the children already have their own styles, and `disabled` needs to be conditional. See above edit please

Comment: So, like `> .input, > .icon { ...`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Is this what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmmagp

Comment: @MichaelCoker Well the styles need to be overridden once the ng-class `disabled` is applied. See above edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest your classes inside your disabled class:

```
   .parent.disabled {
     > .group {
       ...
       > .icon,
       > .input {
         background: grey;
       }
     }
   }
```